# FFMPEG concat intro video to each file in directory (all mp4)

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg, batch

I'm trying to write a concatenation script (for osx) to add an intro.mp4 video to over a hundred other mp4 videos in a directory.

The codec will stay the same mp4, the intro filename will stay the same, but the main video names will change, but all are in the same directory.

I've started writing the bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i CONCAT COMMAND HERE; done
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks all!

Comment: Have you read https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate? What did you try so far? Are the videos with different dimensions, frame rates, et cetera?

Comment: @slhck Thanks for your reply. I ended up making the bash script create a text file then in each iteration of the loop change the contents of the file and run the concat command on the text file each loop.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making the bash script create a temp text file (for the concat command to work on) then in each iteration of the loop change the contents of the text file and run the concat command on the text file each loop. Hope this theory helps someone else.

Comment: Why don't you show your resulting script?

Answer (score 0):

hope You are here  I ask for help. Try FFMPEG concat intro video to each file in directory (all mp4) by using. And no result((

```
@echo off

mkdir output
for %%i in (videos/*.mp4) do (
  echo file 'intro.mp4' > list.txt
  echo file 'videos/%%~nxi' >> list.txt
  ffmpeg -safe 0 -y -f concat -i list.txt -c copy "output/%%~nxi"
)
del list.txt
```