# Mac Teminal Command for Concatenate intro to many videos

Tags: mac, video, ffmpeg, terminal, concatenation

I want to combine 1 intro video to many videos? (Batch)

The file name stay the same with my videos

I have found a code that useful but the problem, it is written in Windows command line, could you translate it into terminal (mac) command line?

Here's the code

```
for %%A IN (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -i "concat:intro.mp4|%%A"  -c copy "new_%%A"
```

Now found new code on here:
[FFMPEG concat intro video to each file in directory (all mp4)](https://superuser.com/questions/890852/ffmpeg-concat-intro-video-to-each-file-in-directory-all-mp4)

But it's on Windows could you translate to terminal command?
Here's the code from thread above

```
@echo off

mkdir output
for %%i in (videos/*.mp4) do (
  echo file 'intro.mp4' > list.txt
  echo file 'videos/%%~nxi' >> list.txt
  ffmpeg -safe 0 -y -f concat -i list.txt -c copy "output/%%~nxi"
)
del list.txt
```

Comment: Most of the answers here will work on Mac https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922352/how-can-i-merge-all-the-videos-in-a-folder-to-make-a-single-video-file-using-ffm

Comment: @peteredhead hi thanks for your reply, most posts in that thread is how to combine multiple videos into one, my case is to add video intro (single video) to every file in directory without changing the filenames

Comment: Please see my answer on the sister-site, SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/1561679/automating-an-fmpeg-task/1561857#1561857

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar answer on the sister-site SuperUser: [Automating an fmpeg task](https://superuser.com/questions/1561679/automating-an-fmpeg-task/1561857#1561857)

I'll put a copy here, with the modification needed to put the same intro file at the beginning of each video.

UDPATE: Modified per comments below, so now it prepends "intro.mp4" to ALL other MP4 files in the current directory.  I tested it, and it works on my Mac with the following files:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jim  staff    25M Apr 19  2019 1.mp4
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jim  staff    21M Apr 19  2019 2.mp4
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jim  staff    16M Jun 13  2017 intro.mp4
```

Just call the script (no arguments), and it generates 2 "merged" files after.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f merge.txt ]
then
    rm merge.txt    
fi

for f in *[.mp4,.mov]
do
  if [ "$f" = "intro.mp4" ]
  then
    continue
  fi
  echo "file intro.mp4" > merge.txt
  echo "file $f" >> merge.txt
  basename=`echo $f | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\.[^.]*$/\1/'`
  ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i merge.txt -c copy "$basename.merged.mp4"
done
```

Comment: hi @jimtut thanks for your reply, i got this "[concat @ 0x7fcd61011200] Line 1: unknown keyword 'intro.mp4'
merge.txt: Invalid data found when processing input" when using your code

Comment: Sorry, the “intro.mo4” should be in double quotes. Also, replace that with the actual name (in double quotes) of the intro video that you want before your videos. As written, you call this once for each video, but you could modify it to read a long list of videos from the command line or maybe an input file, and loop thru all of those files, adding the intro video to all of them. As they say, that will be left as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: thanks for the reply to make the list i use this
for f in ./*[.mp4,.mov]; do echo "file '$f'" >> merge.txt; done 
these are file names that generated from the command 
file './forklaruing.mp4'
file './forkalurance.mp4'
file './forklawinkc.mp4' |
still i got this 
[concat @ 0x7fbcac001e00] Impossible to open './forklaruing.mp4'
merge.txt: No such file or directory | i have put all files on the same directory intro.mp4 and my videos

Comment: See updated script above

Comment: the merge.txt removed, and the file are merged but when i opened the whole videos are replaced by intro.mp4

Comment: likely your videos are not in the same format/size as intro.mp4.  So, when reached the end of copying intro into the merged file, it opened the next file in merge.txt, found that it was of a different format/size of intro, and stopped writing to the merge file, leaving the merge with just a copy of intro.  The files need to be the same format/size, or they can't be merged with the concat command.  It works for me with 3 files recorded from the same iPhone.  You can check your files incl. intro with ffprobe, look at codecs and esp. sizes, reconvert each first to common size/format, if needed.

Comment: hmmm i'm using space in my file names and [concat @ 0x7fefb0006800] Impossible to open '3k Diamond'
merge.txt: No such file or directory but when i delete all 'spaces' it works

Comment: Great!  Please accept this answer if f you’re happy. You could also use single quotes to handle spaces, like this: echo “file ‘$f’” >> merge.txt. Same thing in the basename line too.

Comment: i need my file names stay the same with space, please see my progress on youtube : youtu.be/6QuONX9Vhz4 which part i did it wrong ? | those clips in my directory are 1 video, i separated to 10 Clips

Comment: Go back to what you had in merge.txt in the beginning of that vid.  That file was basically fine, although one of your filenames had single-quotes in it, which will mess up the quoting in merge.txt.  Look, I know you want it to work with your specific filenames, but you need to do some debugging of your own.  Give up your strangley-named filenames for now (do you realize you have a space in the filename, before the .mp4 extension?), and just use some simple names like 1.mp4, etc.  Once it's working, go back to your real filenames (one at a time), and figure out where and why things go wrong.

Comment: i'm working with 1000 files, it will take time to change the name 1 by 1, i need my file names stay same with some of quotes, spaces, coma, those files on youtube are dummies

Comment: OK, then just copy 2 of the files to a new directory, along with the intro vid, and try the script there.  Post the contents of the "ls" command in that directory, and the actual output of the script.  Sharing formatted output like that in a comment isn't possible here for some reason. So, add that output to your question itself, if you have the rights to edit your own question (I think you should).  If you start small and simple, then you can build up to something that will work with 1000's of files.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir output
for f in *.mp4; do
  printf "file 'intro.mp4'\nfile '%s'\n" "$f" > input.txt
  ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i input.txt -c copy output/"$f"
done
```

Assumptions:

- All files are in the same directory.
- Your intro is named `intro.mp4`.
- All inputs have the same attributes (formats, number of streams, type of streams, width, height, profile, sample rate, channel layout, etc). If not, then you'll have to re-encode `intro.mp4` to match the other inputs.
- If macOS `printf` is different than the version in my Linux, and does not work, then you can use two instances of `echo` instead:

  ```
  echo "file 'intro.mp4' > input.txt
  echo "file '$f'" >> input.txt
  ```